Dot Product OpenACC
I'm ask to compute the dot product in a C program. The execise is to compare the sequential version (CPU) with the pararel version (GPU) using OpenACC directives. The issue is that the GPU version is slower than the CPU and that should be like that. What am I doing wrong?
*I'm running the code in a cluster
Sequential:
double dot_product_cpu(int n, double* x, double* y)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result += x[i] * y[i];
    }
    return result;
}

Paralel (GPU):
double dot_product_gpu(int n, double* x, double* y)
{
    double result = 0.0;

    #pragma acc data copyin(x[0:n], y[0:n]) copy(result)
    {
        #pragma acc parallel loop reduction(+:result)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            result += x[i] * y[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

I tried executing with n=10^k where k=1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and none of them worked properly.

Since there's not much compute, it's likely the overhead to copy the data to the GPU that's taking the most time.  Though you should confirm this by profiling your code with Nsight-Systems.
Ideally, you'd hoist the data movement to a higher level in the program and then re-use it multiple times to help amortize this cost.  Here you're copying the data every time dot_product_gpu is called.
